# Unknown plugin "./build/babelRelayPlugin" React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babel-relay

I am working with react-native application and i got error `./build/babelRelayPlugin`

Following are config settings in `.babelrc` file.

```
{
  "passPerPreset": true,
  "presets": [
    {
      "plugins": [
         "./build/babelRelayPlugin",
      ]
    },
    "react-native",
  ]
}
```

Comment: If my answer doesn't work for you, can you post the contents of `./build/babelRelayPlugin`?

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your plugin in the root object like this:

```
{
  "passPerPreset": true,
  "plugins": ["./scripts/babelRelayPlugin"],
  "presets": ["react-app"]
}
```

I was having the same issue and this worked for me in a React project